# Can an android malware persist even after uninstalling it?

Tags: android

I recently installed a modded apk and even after uninstalling it it displays toast message (link  below) each and every time I connect to the internet. I checked installed apps and system apps but there is nothing there. Installed Kaspersky and scanned nothing found. What can I do to know if the device is infected and remove it ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2SvtP

Comment: Under Settings -> Device Manager if you have the checkbox to allow unknown apps to run then disable it.
Under Settings -> Applications look for anything unknown. Its not uncommon for dodgy android apps to use friendly sounding names like "Android Communication Manager" to avoid detection.  Its also possible its escaped OS restrictions - especially on an older outdated system. If that is the case your only option may be a full reset.

Answer (score 2):

First there was [CarrierIQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_IQ#Rootkit_discovery_and_media_attention) (2011) on the HTC EVO 3D (and I think a few other less-known devices), which was a vendor faux pas. It couldn't really be uninstalled -- there had to be a ROM update.

Then came the first system-level Android malware, Droid Kungfu (2011). Kungfu would replace dhcpd and even the boot animation. It wasn't exactly an app that you could uninstall.

Obad (2013) was probably the first Android bootkit. However, it was [relatively-easy to remove](https://blog.threattrack.com/how-to-avoid-and-most-importantly-delete-obad-a-from-your-android-device/) compared to what would come.

One of the nastiest Android bootkits was Mouabad (2014) aka Oldboot -- https://blog.lookout.com/mouabad

Oldboot was heavily-researched:

- http://contagiominidump.blogspot.com/2014/01/android-oldboot-mouabads.html
- http://blog.rootshell.be/2014/06/26/hack-in-paris-2014-wrap-up-day-1/

Later, in December 2014, Palo Alto Networks Unit42 released some research on an Android bootkit they found named Cool Reaper -- https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/content/dam/pan/en_US/assets/pdf/reports/Unit_42/unit42-cool-reaper.pdf -- http://contagiominidump.blogspot.com/2014/12/coolpad-android-devices-coolreaper.html

In 2015, the Cloudsota malware was found to be shipped on Android tablets sold on Amazon -- http://www.cmcm.com/blog/en/security/2015-11-09/842.html

Even recently in 2016 a Yashi smartphone was found to contain a bootkit --
 http://www.tgsoft.it/english/news_archivio_eng.asp?id=693

The Adups Android bootkit was also detailed in late 2016 -- http://www.kryptowire.com/adups_security_analysis.html -- and it was sending private data to China -- https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/11/smartphone_secr.html

The company, Kryptowire, that found Adups also found some Blu Phone that contained bootkit-level malware in 2017, for phones again being sold on Amazon no-less -- https://threatpost.com/amazon-halts-sale-of-android-blu-phone-amid-spyware-concerns/127141/

This topic has also been discussed on the Android StackExchange forum here -- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164898/can-rooting-remove-all-malware-viruses-and-backdoors -- with some suggestions and links to more information on removing system-level rootkits, if not bootkits.